# Replace /" from the 14th column of the file in unix shell script ksh

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, ksh

I have one file which has 10000+ records. There are some bad records which has /" in between the value like below. This is comma delimeter file. I cannot use -E GNU option.

```
"22-11-2020","ABCD",,"ABCD/4400","7644","NY","NY","LAX","ABC","16-09-2023","25-09-2023","02-10-2023","660802","993 14\" X 8\"","28-09-2023",4,"CA",2586,"AA",65.850000,6895.200000,"01-11-2023"
```

I need to remove/replace " from 14th column. I tried below command but its replacing all the double quotes, but not the \ .

```
sed 's/'\"'/''/g' File
```

Need the Output as below :

```
"22-11-2020","ABCD",,"ABCD/4400","7644","NY","NY","LAX","ABC","16-09-2023","25-09-2023","02-10-2023","660802","993 14 X 8","28-09-2023",4,"CA",2586,"AA",65.850000,6895.200000,"01-11-2023"
```

Comment: When you say `/"`, do you mean `\"`? Those are there to escape the `"`s inside `"`-delimited fields so it's valid CSV, you can't just remove them all or `"foo\"` would become `"foo` which would break your CSV, you need to check if each `"` is inside a field or delimiting a field so you only remove (or otherwise handle) `\"`s inside fields. Why do you need to remove the `\"`s anyway though?

Comment: By the way, while escaping with a backslash is done in some CSVs, the CSV "standard", [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), states that a double quote inside a field should be escaped by putting another double quote before it (`"foo""bar"`), not by putting a backslash before it (`"foo\"bar"`) so your CSVs may be more portable if you adopt that convention and it makes them easier to work with in general.

Comment: Finally - since none of your fields contain newlines or commas that means none of them need to be quoted for the CSV to be valid so instead of just removing the `\"`s from 1 field you could just remove all `"`s (and any preceding ```\```) everywhere in your input. If that's not true and your fields CAN contain commas or newlines or double quotes in other fields then you need to include cases where `"`s are needed in your sample input/output so we can see what really needs to be handled.

Comment: @EdMorton In my file getting the bad character between string. " double quotes are there for every character value. But in one of the column getting value as "ABCD \" 123". I want to remove \" from this value so that I can get the value as "ABCD 123" which should be treated as single value. I am able to achieve this using below solution sed & awk when I am working directly in putty. But running same cmd from ksh script removing all the double quotes " which causing the issue for value like "ABCD\,WHITE". It removes double quotes from the value returning as ABCD\,WHITE which comes as 2 colum

Comment: Your example only shows `\"` in the 14th column. Is it a problem when a solution removes all combinations of these 2 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all you want is to replace the string `\"` with the empty string, the following `sed` command should work:

```bash
sed 's/\\"//g' filename
```

If you only want to do this in the 14th column, you could use `awk`;

```bash
awk  'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=",";} {gsub(/\\"/, "", $14); print}' filename
```

Comment: What if I have to remove only from the 14th column?

Comment: @ImSahil: I added an awk script to do that. Sorry for missing that part of the question.

Comment: This works. Thanks!

Comment: This is actually working when I am directly creating the file in putty using cat > file & running the above command. But when the same command I am using in the ksh script it actually removing all the double quotes as well including \".
Is there any option needs to be used after sed or awk?

Comment: @ImSahil You can use backquotes for code. I think you are saying `cat > file` and running..., but perhaps you mean `cat > file &` running ...

Comment: `running the above command.`: which command? The first one given in the answer, or one from your question? Why do you look for additional options, what problem do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F, -lane '$F[13] =~ s{\\"}{}g; print join ",", @F;' in_file > out_file
```

To change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -F, -lane '$F[13] =~ s{\\"}{}g; print join ",", @F;' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F,` : Split into `@F` on `,`, rather than on whitespace.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

The regex uses this modifier:
`/g` : Match the pattern repeatedly.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;s/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{13\}[^,]*\)\\"/\1/;ta' file
```

Iterate backwards through the 14th field removing each occurrence of `\"` and return the result.

Comment: This would remove matches after the 14th column. You also need to stop it at the 14th column `sed -E ':a;s/(([^,]*,){13}[^,]*)\\"([^,]*",)/\1\3/;ta'`

Comment: @HatLess if I apply it to this line `PATTERN: "1","2","3x\\"xy\\"y","4z\\"z"` I get this  result `"1","2","3xxyy","4z\"z"` the `[^,]*` prevents the regexp spilling over in subsequent fields.